# Delete original question when its migrated counterpart gets deleted

Tags: feature-request, migration, deleted-questions

This question [How to block videos from certain users on youtube](https://superuser.com/search?q=how-to-block-videos-from-certain-users-on-youtube) on SU was migrated. But since it's deleted (I can't see it anyway) on webapps I think it should be deleted on SU too.

This should IMO happen to all other questions in the same situation.

Comment: Seems like they should have left it on SU.

Comment: "Your search returned no matches."